# What's the opposite of 'dense'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

I'm referring to densities of materials, not the number of particles per unit volume.

Comment: ... and how exactly do _you_ define the densities of materials?

Comment: We need some context about how you want to use it and what kinds of things you will be referring to.  For example, air that is not dense can be called *thin* or *rarified*.  *Vacuous* means empty or lacking content.  However, balsa wood is not very dense but could not be called vacuous or rarified, and if it was called thin it would refer to a phsyical dimension. Lots of materials are simply called  *low-density* materials. In other cases these are called *lightweight* materials.

Comment: As an aside, it's funny that calling someone *dense* or *vacuous* both means they're stupid.  The first means their head is too dense for information to penetrate, while the second means there's nothing in their head to retain the information that reaches it.

Comment: @jim: "dense" also means  profound and/or esoteric, so it is *also* its own antonym

Comment: I'm confused because the density of materials (in science). In reference to a material's density, it IS a measure of the number of particles per unit volume.  Which definition then, are using?

Comment: @balancedmama- density is actually a measure of the *mass* per unit volume.  The number of *particles* required to achieve that mass is immaterial.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of *sparse* or *lean*, depending on context.

Answer (score 2):

Density is a property of matter describing how closely packed together its molecules are ([dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/density)).  It is essentially the same use as a population description where many people packed closely together is considered a dense population.

Because everything has a density, but different densities are relative, the closest thing to the opposite of Dense you can get is either an absence of matter all together or Not Dense, or Less Dense.  I'm sorry I can't offer anything better, but in all my years learning and teaching chemistry, I don't believe I've ever seen or heard an actual opposite for the term.

Comment: If the "material" in question were a gas, you could use _rarefied_. I can't think of a general term applicable to solids either, though.

Comment: "vacuum" (and perhaps loosely "vacuous")?

Comment: Hah that's great!  It is a different Form of the word though.  Material has density.  Can you say it has vacuousness?